# Can a function take an argument by const reference *without* accepting temporaries as an argument?

Tags: c++, reference

Motivating example:

Suppose we have a class `Foo` and a class `ObservesFoo` that has a non-owning pointer to an instance of a `Foo`. We could write that as follows:

```
class Foo {};

class ObservesFoo
{
    Foo* p_foo = nullptr;

    ObservesFoo(Foo* t_foo) : p_foo(t_foo) { }
};
```

But maybe I don't consider `nullptr` to be a valid value for `p_foo` to have. I can write a different constructor for `ObservesFoo` that'll enforce this requirement without me needing to do something like throwing if `t_foo` is invalid:

```
ObservesFoo(Foo& t_foo) : p_foo(&t_foo) { }
```

Then I say to myself, "Hang on, this constructor isn't *changing* `t_foo`. Shouldn't I take it as a `const Foo&`?" But then if I write the function like this, it might accept a temporary `Foo` as its argument, whose lifetime would immediately end as soon as the constructor returned, which would obviate any guarantees I got from ensuring that `p_foo` wasn't `nullptr`, because now it could very easily be a dangling pointer.

Is there a clean way to get the middle ground between the `Foo&` constructor and the `const Foo&` constructor?

Comment: `ObservesFoo(const Foo* ptr_foo) : p_foo(ptr_foo) { }`?

Comment: That doesn't seem like it would do anything about the possibility that `nullptr` is, as far as that constructor is concerned, a completely valid value for `ptr_foo`.

Comment: Parameters don't extend lifetimes of the caller's arguments.

Comment: Yes, I suppose the question is a bit awkwardly worded. Editing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `const` doesn't interfere with how you use the object, and you never need to rebind what object is being observed, and the observed Foo instance is guaranteed to outlive its observer(s), then a reference will work.

If you delete the constructor taking an rvalue-reference to a Foo, you will prevent the accidental lifetime extension you mentioned:

```
class ObservesFoo
{
    Foo const& p_foo;

    ObservesFoo(Foo const& t_foo) : p_foo(t_foo) { }
    ObservesFoo(Foo&& t_foo) = delete;
};
```

Comment: Minor nitpick, `ObservesFoo(Foo&& t_foo)` is not a move constructor.  Those have the form of `class_name(class_name&&)`.  Still +1

Comment: I'd written the toy class as `Foo* p_foo` instead of `Foo const& p_foo` because it means the automatically generated constructors for `ObservesFoo` aren't invalidated. However this solution to deleting a `Foo&&` constructor seems like it would work regardless of the change to the underlying member variable. Obviously it's still possible to hand it a `Foo` whose lifetime isn't what `ObservesFoo` expects, but this seems like it would make it harder to do something silly.

Comment: Thanks.  Knew that but wasn't thinking as I typed it.  Will fix!